# android listener interface variable null

Tags: android, interface

I refer to various codes and wrote as follows.

```
public CustomView bbv;
bbv.setOnVariableChanged(new CustomView.VariableChanger() {  //error(line:132)
    @Override
    public void onVariableChanged() {
         real = true;
    }

});
```

and

```
VariableChanger onVariableChanged;

run(){

    ....
    if (count == 10) {
        if (onVariableChanged != null)
            onVariableChanged.onVariableChanged();
}

public void setOnVariableChanged(VariableChanger listener) {
    this.onVariableChanged = listener;
}

public interface VariableChanger {
    void onVariableChanged();
}
```

When the count is 10,

bbv.setOnVariableChanged (new CustomView.VariableChanger () throws an error.

I don't know what's wrong.

Thank you for answer.

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void hci.parrot_bebop.view.BebopVideoView.setOnVariableChanged(hci.parrot_bebop.view.BebopVideoView$VariableChanger)' on a null object reference 
    at hci.parrot_bebop.activity.BebopActivity$1$1.run(BebopActivity.java:132)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

---

Comment: `throws an error` which?

Comment: What is error log

Comment: Kindly post error log. SO community need error log to answer any question.

Comment: Oops! Sorry.
I added an error message.

Comment: have you initialize CustomView bbv = new CustomView()?

Comment: @Piyush hello. 
No.CustomView inherits from TextureView.
So I wrote "public BebopVideoView bbv;"

"public BebopVideoView bbv = new BebopVideoView(this)" 
An error occurs in the " Attempt to invoke method~"

Comment: Have you declared that custom view in your xml file?

Comment: If your custom view is inherited from TextView there are two ways to initialize either by findviewbyid() or by using new

Comment: @Piyush Yes. I declared xml file. I see the contents of the custom view on my smartphone screen.

Comment: @Piyush OMG... I solved it right away thanks to your comment.
I never thought it was an initialization problem.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: @kimms anytime!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Piyush's comments**

My CustomView is inherited from TextureView.

So in the initialization section
"CustomView bbv = new CustomView ()" could not be used.

However, I can initialize it with by findviewbyid () or by using new.

like, 
"bbv = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.*YOUR VIEW ID*)"